# Behavior of Union Type in Typescript In Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I have this code:

```
interface Course {
  code: string;
  name: string;
  user: number | {
    id: number;
    name: string;
  };
}
```

Which means a course object can have either the user object or the user key.
Now I fetch the course from the backend through http request. Actually, backend can send either the user key or the user object as a part of the course object, that is why I am using this type for the user.

```
this.http.get<Course>('/api.course-endpoint/').subscribe(
  response => {
    const userId = response.user.id;
  }
);
```

Here the line `const userId = response.user.id;` is generating this error.

```
error TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'number | { id: number; name: string; }'.
Property 'id' does not exist on type 'number'.
```

How to fix it? And why it is happening?

Answer (score 1):

You are saying a course has a 'user' which can be either a number or an object containing 'id'.

So, to fix it, it should be 'response.course.user' and you could check if user is object or number. If it's number, maybe you should load it from the server.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid errors, you can use the Object Chaining (?. ) operators, this validates if your Object has this key, if this is not the case, the variable you assign (userId) will be `undefined`, then, you can use conditional sentences to handle the following code flow without errors

Referent link (Object Chaining): https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Encadenamiento_opcional

Example:

```
this.http.get<Course>('/api.course-endpoint/').subscribe(
  response => {
    const userId = response?.user?.id;
  }
);
```

Comment: Maybe you need to check if the user was set as number, if this happened you will never get the id of data type number.
`this.http.get<Course>('/api.course-endpoint/').subscribe(
    response => {
      const userId = typeof(response.user) === 'number' ? response.user : response.user?.id;
    }
  );`
Or something like that.